# Error: Unrecognized datatype for attribute "users.username"

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am getting  error unrecognized datatype in nodejs and sequelize orm  while console.log(db.users) in app.js file.

code for app.js file is

```
const db = require('./models/index');
console.log(db.users);
```

I have defined the user model as following.please check it for error.

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class users extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  users.init({
    username: {
      dialectTypes: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      dialectTypes: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      dialectTypes: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
      dialectTypes: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    coverPic: {
      dialectTypes: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    profilePic: {
      dialectTypes: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    city: {
      dialectTypes: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    website: {
      dialectTypes: DataTypes.STRING,
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'users',
  });
  return users;
};
```

Comment: Try changing `dialectTypes` to `type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code lies in the definition of data types for the user model fields. The `dialectTypes` property does not exist in Sequelize, and using it will result in an unrecognized data type error. Instead, you should use `DataTypes` directly when defining the data types for your model's fields. Modify your code as follows:

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class users extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }

  users.init(
    {
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      coverPic: DataTypes.STRING,
      profilePic: DataTypes.STRING,
      city: DataTypes.STRING,
      website: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'users',
    }
  );

  return users;
};
```

In the updated code, I removed the `dialectTypes` property and directly used `DataTypes.STRING` for string fields. For fields where you don't need specific data types, you can simply specify them without the `type` property, as I did with `name`, `coverPic`, `profilePic`, `city`, and `website`.